# how to skip a unittest case in python 2.6

Tags: python, unit-testing

`unittest.skip*` decorators and methods as below ([see here for more details](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html)) were added since python2.7 and i found they are quite useful.

```
unittest.skip(reason)
unittest.skipIf(condition, reason)
unittest.skipUnless(condition, reason)
```

However, my question is how we should do the similar if working with python2.6?

Comment: Good question.  It looks like skipping is implemented via a custom exception, which doesn't exist in python2.6.  So it looks like just borrowing some of the code from the python2.7 tree might be out of the question...  You could see if you can borrow the whole package and hope it's backwards compatible...

Answer (score 5):

Use [`unittest2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2).

The following code imports the right `unittest` in a manner transparent to the rest of your code:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info < (2, 7):
    import unittest2 as unittest
else:
    import unittest
```

Answer (score 5):

If you can't use unittest2 and don't mind having a different number of tests in Python 2.6, you can write simple decorators that make the tests disappear:

```
try:
    from unittest import skip, skipUnless
except ImportError:
    def skip(f):
        return lambda self: None

    def skipUnless(condition, reason):
        if condition:
            return lambda x: x
        else:
            return lambda x: None
```

Comment: could you pls expand your answer, by providing why. Thx

Answer (score 2):

If you have the liberty of installing additional packages, you can use [`unittest2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2) which is Python 2.7 unittest backported to Python 2.3+. It does contain the skip decorators.