# Contract of a decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, metaprogramming, python-decorators

*Contract:* A function that takes function as argument and returns a function[i.e., modified(or same) version of passed function]. Passed function, here is, `square`, for example.

```
@floatify
def square(n):
   return n*n
```

Is decorator suppose to return only decorated version of passed function, but nothing else?

Comment: The most common case is to return a new function (a wrapper) which makes use of the passed function, which is not a modified version of the passed function.

Comment: @AlexHall Modified function I mean, a function that uses passed function , in any case.

Comment: OK, I just wanted to clarify because sometimes a decorator may simply set attributes on the passed in function and then return it back, which is what I thought you meant by a modified version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is supposed to only return a function, but nothing stops you from returning anything you'd want.

```
>>> def d(x):
...   return "hello"
...
>>> @d
... def f():
...   return "world"
...
>>> f
'hello'
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>>
```

Comment: @ratskin including a decorator above the function is the same as adding `function = decorator(function)` after it.

Comment: Nothing stopping me, to return anything, is an easy way to mis-utilize the idea of decorator. Probably you should remove that phrase, in your answer

Comment: @overexchange kichik's point is that Python doesn't _prevent_ you from doing silly things like that with decorators, it's up to _you_ to utilize them correctly. Why does Python allow this? Well, it would add complexity to the interpreter to add such a check, and in some situations there may be valid reasons for a decorator to return a non-function.

Answer (score 5):

The decorating function ought to return a function because whatever it returns will get bound to the original function's name. So it's rather confusing if the returned object isn't a function (or some other callable, like a class constructor, or callable class instance).

Generally the returned function ought to have a function signature that's compatible with the original function, but I guess it's ok if the returned function also takes additional args. Also, the return type of the returned function ought to be compatible with that of the original function.

A decorated function is kind-of like a subclass of the original function, and so it makes sense to adhere to the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

The decorating function *could* have side-effects: eg, it could modify some global. That may be useful, eg for logging purposes; OTOH, functions should generally avoid having side-effects.

FWIW, some of the standard function decorators return non-function callables, the most common one is probably `@classmethod`.

---

There's nothing particularly magical about decorators. As Jared Goguen mentions in a comment,

```
@decorator
def some_function(args):
    #etc
```

is identical to

```
def some_function(args):
    #etc

some_function = decorator(some_function)
```

The second form is a little longer, but more powerful, since you can choose to bind the returned function to a different name, if you want. Some things that can be easily accomplished using the longer syntax can be difficult if not downright impossible to do using the `@` syntax.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34558606/2482744) is an example of a decorator which returns a non-function in a way that is useful.

Comment: @JaredGoguen the lambdas are the actual decorators, while `skip[Unless]` are functions which produce decorators. So the decorated function may be replaced with `None`.

Comment: @AlexHall Ugh, that's really confusing, it seems like the return type is inconsistent... `skip` results in the trivial function, `skipUnless(True)` results in the original function, and `skipUnless(False)` results in `None`. It seems like that last case is a mistake and it was intended to return the trivial function as well.

Comment: @JaredGoguen no, `skip(reason)(test_function)` and `skipUnless(False, reason)(test_function)` both return `None` so that `test_function` doesn't run as a test. It's correct.

Comment: @alex Gotcha, the argument name of `f` in `skip(f)` is misleading.

Comment: @AlexHall But [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81S01c9zytE) it says, to not return a non-function, if you think about decorator. How to understand this?

Comment: @overexchange I was just giving an example of an exceptional case. The point is that decorators can do all sorts of very different things and there are very few restrictions that apply in all cases. In that sense it's hard to answer your question. But *most* of the time they will work as described in your question or in this answer: they return a callable which can be called in a similar way to the original.

Answer (score -3):

Decorator can be used as

- Registration decorator
- Functional decorator
- Parameterized decorator
- Class-based decorator

Code in your query is *Functional decorator*, that replace *decorated function*(`square`) with `wrapper`. `wrapper` does the following:

- calls `f(n)`
- applies `float` to `result` and returns it.

```
def floatify(f):
   def wrapper(n):
      result = f(n)
      return float(result)
   return wrapper
```

**Contract of *functional decorator***:

The *replacement function* usually honors the contract of the *decorated function*:

- Accept same number/kinds of args
- Return result of compatible type

The *replacement function* should preserve metadata from the *decorated function*

- Important for debugging and other meta-programming purposes, Use `@functools.wraps(f)`