# Contract of a class based decorator

Tags: python, decorator

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45640690/3317808) talks about contract of a  functional decorator.

Below is the code for class based decorator,

```
def hello_world(obj):
   return 'Hello World'

@hello_world
class C:
   pass
```

---

It is obvious that class based decorator accept `Class` type object as parameter. For returning an object,

What is the contract of a class based decorator?

Comment: The `hello_world()` function doesn't look like a proper class decorator to me (and certainly doesn't work)—so it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @martineau Why `hello_world()` doesn't look like a proper class decorator? What rules do you follow to write a class based decorator? I know the rules to apply decorator on a `function` type object

Comment: Conceptually, it looks like you want to play with inheritance, where the child class would act as a decorator.

Comment: Decorator is a wrapper - it should return a result of some manipulation over a class; in the degenerated case - class itself. Try to instantiate your class - and you'll see why this code is meaningless

Comment: In not a proper class decorator because it doesn't decorate the class `obj` it's passed as an argument. Instead it will turn any class it's used on into a a string which will cause `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` when any attempt is made to create an instance of the class, such as `c = C()`.

Comment: You ask about a "contract" but there is no such thing in Python, as already demonstrated in the [linked answer from kichik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45640725/674039).

Comment: @martineau  That doesn't make it "not a proper decorator" - it's probably not a useful decorator, but that's still a syntactically correct decorator.

Comment: @wim In the same link, read my answer and provide feedback

Comment: @wim what's the use of code that does not work? "Proper decorator" serves a certain purpose - syntactically correct useless decorator does not serve any purpose..

Comment: @volcano Would you say that code is useful, in a case where, `hello_world()` returns, say  a `function` type object?

Comment: @wim: By "proper" I didn't mean in the syntactic sense, I meant in the sense of [decorating](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/decorate) something. Turning classes into strings isn't that sort of thing. In fact, now that I think more about it, all a "class based decorator" would be is decorator implemented as a class rather than a function—regardless of what kind of thing it's meant to decorate.

Comment: Decorator should do some manipulation on passed function/class, and return the result of this manipulation. Anything else is a waste of effort.

Comment: @volcano Firstly, Decorator concept is language agnostic.  If I take your idea of a decorator and try understand class based decorator(cbd) used in *Angular 2*, then, I need to just ignore why cbd([`@Component`](https://medium.com/@ttemplier/angular2-decorators-and-class-inheritance-905921dbd1b7)) in *Angular 2* written the way it is? This is just an example.

Comment: overexchange: Returning a function instead of a string doesn't sound that useful either and could still cause issues later when an attempt is to create an instance of the resulting "class" which is really now a function (so avoids the `not callable` error). Maybe in some weird situation where the function replacing the class returned a class it might be useful.

Comment: @overexchange, don't bring _javascript_ (abomination) concepts into Python. Languages have different constructs and different purposes. JS is mostly DSL (domain specific language) for WEB; Python is generic-purpose language. _array_ means different things in C and Python

Comment: @volcano Just ignore my comments from now

Comment: @overexchange, the smart thing to do. I will. I would not want to interfere with such a valiant strife for ignorance :)

Comment: @volcano  Just because you can not think of wider use-cases it does not mean they don't exist.  You could implement, for example, an `@skip` decorator which replaces a function object with `None` it the module namespace in order to exclude it from a test runner's collection phase (*note*: this is not how unittest's `skip` and `skipIf` decorators are implemented).  Imagining there is some "contract" that a function decorator should always return a function, when there is no such restriction in the language, is not useful to anybody.

Comment: @wim So what you are saying, is that a decorator can do anything it likes, and sometimes it will work and sometimes it won't.

While technically correct, you are also not being very helpful in a practical sense.

Comment: @wim, You can - it will cause exception, Again - meaningless argument for the sake of argument? Decorators as mock object do have their use - which purpose has decorator that causes exception?

Comment: @volcano No, you're mistaken.  That will not cause exception.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with your terminology - when people talk about a "class decorator" they may mean a "class based decorator", i.e. it's a decorator implemented with a *callable class* instead of with a function.

There is no "contract" difference between a class decorator and a normal decorator.  Arguably, there is no such thing as a "class decorator" - it's just a decorator that happens to be decorating the class.

```
@dec
def foo():
    pass

@dec
class C:
    pass
```

This above, is the same as this below:

```
def foo():
    pass

foo = dec(foo)

class C:
    pass

C = dec(C)
```

It's entirely up to the implementation of `dec` what to do when the argument received is a function object vs a class object, this is independent of the decorator pattern itself.

In most use cases, decorators on functions should return functions and decorators on classes should return classes, but there is no such restriction in the language.  A decorator on a function could, for example, return an instance of a callable class.

Comment: You are talking about the mechanics: How decorators work? which isn't the question. Please read my linked answer

Comment: I read the linked post.  What is this "contract" you're asking about, because you've provided no reference about that - is it just a term you made up yourself?

Comment: I think he's asking what's a "class decorator" is supposed to do: return a class

Comment: @Alvaro Yes, that's what I meant by contract.

Comment: @overexchange  "functional decorators" is a term you made up, and the "contract" also seems to be something you're imagining.  And using your own self-answer as a reference does not add much credibility.

Comment: @wim term is not adding any confusion. Contract is what Alvaro mentioned in above comment. I would like to know the idea to invalidate my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, there is an implicit expectation that any function or class designed to be used as a decorator should return an object that behaves in the same way as the provided object. However, nothing in Python enforces this "contract."

If your decorator is given a class and returns a string (as in your example), people might be confused because a string most likely does not behave in the same way as a class. When decorating a class, you may want to avoid removing instance/class/static methods or class variables. You might want to alter them or add new ones, but it would be strange to strip functionality defined in the class body through the use of a decorator. An example of this is shown below:

```
def bad_decorator(cls):
    del cls.method
    return cls

@bad_decorator
class Test(object):
    def method(self):
        return 'test method'

print(Test().method()) # AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'method'
```

In essence, your `class -> string` example violates this implicit expectation because we can no longer use the class as defined in its body. Borrowing from the duck typing nomenclature, there is some expectation that your returned object will still quack like a duck. Likewise, it is generally encouraged to follow the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) when writing Python.

Comment: Yes, The replacement function(`wrapper`) should honor the contract of the decorated function(`test_function`). This is the reason, I disagree with this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439924/contract-of-a-class-based-decorator#comment81835809_47439924). But you are talking about Functional decorators, as I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45653907/3317808). Am looking similar inputs on class based decorators.

Comment: @overexchange: You still don't seem to understand the difference between a "class **based** decorator" and a "class decorator". Why is this question about a "contract" important to you anyway?

Comment: @overexchange I updated the answer to provide an example decorating a class, but it shouldn't really matter

Comment: @martineau Important because, I can start writing/using them and avoid scenarios like *when you are decorating a class, you probably don't want to remove* kind of ambiguity, mentioned in the answer.

Comment: *decorator should return the same type that it is provided* ... well ... not really .. it just has to duck type correctly.  e.g. decorator on a function returning instance of callable class.

Comment: @overexchange: Design by Contract is just a software design approach independent of any particular language. In Python decorators are just semantic sugar and can be implemented (based) on anything callable, which happens to include both functions and classes, the ways it's most commonly done. When you see one applied, there's generally an implicit "contract" that the decorated thing will still be usable in the same ways it would be if it were undecorated. If a design changed that postcondition/invariant and documented it, it might be considered an acceptable thing to do.

Comment: @wim agreed and updated